# I need help populating my dropdown with my JSON response

Tags: jquery, json

I'm getting JSON back in this format from my C# webmethod:

```
{"d":["ADAMS CITY","BOULDER","ANTON","ARBOLES"]}
```

I now have a asp.net dropdown. Well, it renders as a html dropdown with `#city` id.

I'm getting a success alert on my AJAX request. How can I populate these results into my #city dropdown?

Tried this:

```
 success:
                function (data) {
                var values = eval(data.d);
                var ddl = $("#parkCity");
                $('option', ddl).remove();
                ddl.html(data);
                alert("Cities loaded");
            },
```

Comment: Added some code I found on the net. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that should do fine inside of your `success` callback:

```
var $select = $("#parkcity");

$.each(data.d, function(i, el) {
    console.log(el);
    $select.append($("<option />", { text: el }));
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/z2D8f/

Or an alternative that appends the HTML all at once, which is probably faster:

```
var html = $.map(data.d, function(el) {
    return "<option>" + el + "</option>";
});

$("#parkcity").append(html.join(''));
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/pUhw2/