# Load JSON data into dropdown

Tags: jquery, json

I have one JSON returning dropdown values (Value and Text). I need to load that data into my dropdown. I have no idea how can i load those data's into dropdown. please tell me the possibilities.

**Code**

```
    $('#SupplierId').change(function () {
    var a = $(this).val();
    $.post('@Url.Action("MatchPoNo", "Subscriptions")', { Id: a }, function (data) {

        $("#PoNo").select2({

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: [**append()**](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [I need help populating my dropdown with my JSON response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950025/i-need-help-populating-my-dropdown-with-my-json-response?lq=1), [Populating dropdown menu with JSON Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205559/populating-dropdown-menu-with-json-data), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try will work:

```
var data = [
    {val: 1, text: "One"},
    {val: 2, text: "Two"},
];

$("#PoNo").append(function() {
    return $.map(data, function(el, i) {
        return '<option value=' + el.val + '>' + el.text + '</option>'; 
        // return $('<option>', {val: el.val, text: el.text});
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SgCXy/

However it would be nice if you posted example of your json.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this, but something like this in your callback should work. This assumes that you are returning a javascript array.

```
data.each(function(){
 $option = $("<option></option>");
 $option.val(this.value);
 $option.html(this.text);
 $('#dropdown').append($option);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use [JQuery view engine](https://jocapc.github.io/jquery-view-engine/) and just load the array into a dropdown:

```
var data = [
    {"text":"North","value":"N"},
    {"text":"West","value":"W"},
    {"text":"South","value":"S","selected":true},
    {"text":"East","value":"E"}
];
$("#dropdown").view(data);
```

See details here: https://jocapc.github.io/jquery-view-engine/docs/ajax-dropdown