# JavaScript / JQuery to load JSON data into HTML5 dynamic drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have been trying to get this right and nothing I am doing is working. I made a hard-coded version of a dynamic drop down menu where the second field (State) provides information based on conditions set forth by the selection of the first field (Country).

Here is the hard coded html and JavaScript file:

form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lan="en">
    <head>
<!--        <script type="text/javascript" src="sampleForm.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="sampleForm.js"</script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8";
        <title>Select Country and State</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="formStyle.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
  <form id="sampleForm" enctype='application/json'>
        <option id='country'>Select Your Country</option>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

populate.js:

```
function populate(s1,s2){
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  s2.innerHTML="";
  if(s1.value=="Canada"){
    var getStates = ["|","alberta|Alberta", "britishColumbia|British Columbia", "manitoba|Manitoba", "newBrunswick|New Brunswick", "newfoundlandAndLabrador|Newfoundland and Labrador", "northwestTerritories|Northwest Territories", "novaScotia|Nova Scotia", "nunavut|Nunavut", "ontario|Ontario", "princeEdwardIsland|Prince Edward Island", "quebec|Quebec", "saskatchewan|Saskatchewan", "yukonTerritory|Yukon Territory"];
  } else if(s1.value=="Pakistan"){
    var getStates = ["|","balochistan|Balochistan", "northWestFrontierProvince|North-West Frontier Province", "punjab|Punjab", "sindh|Sindh", "islamabadCapitalTerritory|Islamabad Capital Territory", "federallyAdministeredTribalAreas|Federally Administered Tribal Areas"];
  } else if(s1.value=="USA"){
    var getStates = ["|","alabama|Alabama", "alaska|Alaska", "arizona|Arizona", "arkansas|Arkansas", "california|California", "colorado|Colorado", "connecticut|Connecticut", "delaware|Delaware", "districtOfColumbia|District of Columbia", "florida|Florida", "georgia|Georgia", "hawaii|Hawaii", "idaho|Idaho", "illinois|Illinois"];
  }
  for(var myState in getStates){
    var pair = getStates[myState].split("|");
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = pair[0];
    newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
    s2.options.add(newOption);
  }
}
```

I have a JSON file that has Country keys and State values. I want to call the keys and values into the dropdown menu options. Based on the answer I found at

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      var data = countryState.json;

      var $selectCountry = $("#country");

      $.each(data.d, function(i, el) {
          console.log(el);
          $selectCountry.append($("<option />", { text: el }));
      });
  });
```

Here is the new html file:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lan="en">
            <head>
        <!--        <script type="text/javascript" src="sampleForm.js"></script>-->
        <!--    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="getData.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="moreScript.js"></script>
            <meta charset="UTF-8";
                <title>Select Country and State</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="formStyle.css" />
            </head>
            <body>
          <form id="locationSelector" enctype='application/json'>
                <br id="selectCountry"></br>
                <select id='country'></select>
                <br id="selectState">=</br>
                <select id='state'></select>
            </form>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Here is a JavaScript file referenced by the html file:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      var data = "countryState.JSON";

      var $selectCountry = $("#country");

      $.each(data.d, function(i, el) {
          console.log(el);
          $selectCountry.append($("<option />", { text: el }));
      });
  });
```

Here is the JSON file:

http://learn.ryanschostag.com/json-file-of-countries-and-states/

My new JavaScript file is based on the answer by Andrew Whitaker at [I need help populating my dropdown with my JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950025/i-need-help-populating-my-dropdown-with-my-json-response?lq=1).

My JSON file was found at gitHub.

I have tried making the src of my form the JSON file. I tried a lot of things for about an hour now, and can't get the data to populate to the drop-down menus, let alone make them dynamic based on conditions.

I don't know how to code the conditions `if / else` statements and `functions` relating to calling the JSON data and passing it to the drop down options.

Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: TLDR; ... :-( You really should try to extrapolate the real issues you face and post a question with the offending code... If you post your whole page here I'm afraid you'll not get many useful answers... :-(

Comment: In the past, I got requests to add more information and that my information was not enough. I provided what I have that works, which is the first two sets of code for form.html and populate.js. These do not have anything to do with getting data from the JSON file. I need to now make the form get data from the JSON file and I am lost.

Comment: Is your console showing any errors?

Comment: @AhsN sorry for the late response. I watched some video that resolved the issue. thank you